# How to get spatial types working in EF?

Tags: entity-framework, types, spatial

I have a table with a SQL Geometry column. Now I'm trying to work with EF but the mapper doesn't want to include it (it should be supported by now, [as I saw here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh859721)). Also, I can't find the Spatial Types in the EF Designer [as I saw here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/05/12/spatial-types-in-the-entity-designer.aspx).

I have done so far:

```
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework –IncludePrerelease
'EntityFramework 5.0.0-beta2' already installed.
MyProject already has a reference to 'EntityFramework 5.0.0-beta2'.
```

and after this, the version of the referenced EnitiyFramework.dll is:

```
4.4.0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, if you are targeting .net 4, it would not work: `Some features are only available when writing an application that targets .NET 4.5. This includes enum support, spatial data types, table-valued functions and the performance improvements. If you are targeting .NET 4.0 you still get all the bug fixes and other minor improvements.`
source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/03/22/ef5-beta-2-available-on-nuget.aspx

Also, if you are targeting 4.5, look here: [How to get enums working in mvc4 with Entity Framework 5 Beta 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896692/how-to-get-enums-working-in-mvc4-with-entity-framework-5-beta-2)

Comment: downloading... btw, is it safe to use this beta versions for production sites?

Comment: I did not tried it yet, but I encountered a lot of problems when I tried to uninstall the 4.5 preview (.net 4 stopped working, needed to format machine), so I suggest you to try it on a VM first, if possible.

Comment: Awww, too late. I tried with 4.5 but it did not work. Now I'm downloading VS2011 beta.

Comment: Good luck, let me know if it works... but I hope it work on 2010 too, at least when the final .net 4.5 is released.

Comment: Leo is right. Only .net 4.5 for now. Anyway, if you want a step by step tutorial I've blogged about it: http://build-failed.blogspot.pt/2012/04/entity-framework-5-and-spatial-data.html

Comment: After all I could not install VS11... error on 99%. However, I'm 100% sure this is the answer :)